# Error Inflating Class ToggleButton

Tags: android

I get this error on devices below Android 5

It is showing a problem with:

```
Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/expandable_header_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02006d 
Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_expand_less_24px.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020071
XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag vector
```

But both those xml files are in my normal drawable folder and in `drawable-v21` folder so whats the problem here or is the problem the tags

Logcat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #179: Error inflating class android.widget.ToggleButton
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                                                                         at com.candyx.testapp.main.players.PlayerSearchFragment.onCreateView(PlayerSearchFragment.java:67)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                         at com.candyx.testapp.main.players.PlayerSearchFragment.onCreateView(PlayerSearchFragment.java:67) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/expandable_header_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02006d
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1923)
                                                                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:614)
                                                                         at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
                                                                         at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:68)
                                                                         at android.widget.ToggleButton.<init>(ToggleButton.java:51)
                                                                         at android.widget.ToggleButton.<init>(ToggleButton.java:64)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                         at com.candyx.testapp.main.players.PlayerSearchFragment.onCreateView(PlayerSearchFragment.java:67) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_expand_less_24px.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020071
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1923)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881)
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1920)
                                                                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) 
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:614) 
                                                                         at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107) 
                                                                         at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:68) 
                                                                         at android.widget.ToggleButton.<init>(ToggleButton.java:51) 
                                                                         at android.widget.ToggleButton.<init>(ToggleButton.java:64) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                         at com.candyx.testapp.main.players.PlayerSearchFragment.onCreateView(PlayerSearchFragment.java:67) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                      Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:877)
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1920)
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659) 
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173) 
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:881) 
                                                                         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818) 
                                                                         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1920) 
                                                                         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) 
                                                                         at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:614) 
                                                                         at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107) 
                                                                         at android.widget.CompoundButton.<init>(CompoundButton.java:68) 
                                                                         at android.widget.ToggleButton.<init>(ToggleButton.java:51) 
                                                                         at android.widget.ToggleButton.<init>(ToggleButton.java:64) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
                                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
                                                                         at com.candyx.testapp.main.players.PlayerSearchFragment.onCreateView(PlayerSearchFragment.java:67) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677) 
                                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

expandable_header_selector.xml

```
selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_expand_less_24px" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_expand_more_24px" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

ic_expand_less_24px.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">

<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:pathData="M12 8l-6 6 1.41 1.41L12 10.83l4.59 4.58L18 14z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: Do you use `support-vector-drawable` in your project? Without it (and some additional configuration) it won't work on pre-Lollipop devices.